# Units of frequency when using FFT in NumPy

Tags: numpy, signal-processing, fft

I am using the FFT function in NumPy to do some signal processing. I have array called `signal`
which has one data point for each hour and has a total of 576 data points. I use the following code on `signal` to look at its fourier transform.

```
t = len(signal)
ft = fft(signal,n=t)
mgft=abs(ft)
plot(mgft[0:t/2+1])
```

I see two peaks but I am unsure as to what the units of the x axis are i.e., how they map onto hours? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given sampling rate `FSample` and transform blocksize `N`, you can calculate the frequency resolution `deltaF`, sampling interval `deltaT`, and total capture time `capT` using the relationships:

```
deltaT = 1/FSample = capT/N
deltaF = 1/capT = FSample/N
```

Keep in mind also that the FFT returns value from `0` to `FSample`, or equivalently `-FSample/2` to `FSample/2`. In your plot, you're already dropping the `-FSample/2` to `0` part. NumPy includes a helper function to calculate all this for you: [fftfreq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html).

For your values of `deltaT = 1 hour` and `N = 576`, you get `deltaF = 0.001736 cycles/hour = 0.04167 cycles/day`, from `-0.5 cycles/hour` to `0.5 cycles/hour`. So if you have a magnitude peak at, say, bin 48 (and bin 528), that corresponds to a frequency component at `48*deltaF = 0.0833 cycles/hour = 2 cycles/day.`

In general, you should apply a [window function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) to your time domain data before calculating the FFT, to reduce [spectral leakage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage). The Hann window is almost never a bad choice. You can also use the `rfft` function to skip the `-FSample/2, 0` part of the output. So then, your code would be:

```
ft = np.fft.rfft(signal*np.hanning(len(signal)))
mgft = abs(ft)
xVals = np.fft.fftfreq(len(signal), d=1.0) # in hours, or d=1.0/24 in days
plot(xVals[:len(mgft)], mgft)
```

Comment: @JoeKington - Thanks! I could not find that in the docs today, I thought I had hallucinated it.

Comment: Also note that each FFT result bin has a width, thus a potential error range, of  around a half hour in your case.  Or of around a larger 1 hour or more if you window.

Comment: Maybe `xVals = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(signal), d=1.0)` then `plot(xVals, mgft)` also work?

Answer (score 0):

Result of fft transformation doesn't map to HOURS, but to frequencies contained in your dataset.  It would be beneficial to have your transformed graph so we can see where the spikes are.

You might be having spike at the beginning of the transformed buffer, since you didn't do any windowing.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the dimensional units of frequency from an FFT are the same as the dimensional units of the sample rate attributed to the data fed to the FFT, for example: per meter, per radian, per second, or in your case, per hour.

The scaled units of frequency, per FFT result bin index, are N / theSampleRate, with the same dimensional units as above, where N is the length of the full FFT (you might only be plotting half of this length in the case of strictly real data).

Note that each FFT result peak bin represents a filter with a non-zero bandwidth, so you might want to add some uncertainty or error bounds to the result points you map onto frequency values.  Or even use an interpolation estimation method, if needed and appropriate for the source data.